# Can you create a custom model using GPT-3 to answer questions only about a specific topic?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, gpt-3

I'm using GPT-3 to create a chatbot that can answer questions related to a specific topic. Can GPT-3 be trained to detect questions that are irrelevant to the topic and refuse to answer them?

Example: Let's say I want to create a chatbot that can only answer questions about
Javascript. If it is asked to list the seven wonders of the world, it should refuse to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been successful for me, you may wish to try it as well.

I want you to act as a javascript guide. You are here to help answer any questions I may have about the language. If I have any questions,  you will do your best to provide a helpful response. Please note that if my question is not related to Javascript, you have to write only "Error". Let's get started.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to get the model to work as expected with some clever prompt engineering. Thank you.